# What's the best way to create a confirmatin modal window in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, confirmation

What is the best way to create a confirmation modal window in asp.net mvc 4?

Currently I have:

```
if (ViewBag.deleteIsVisible)
{
  <button onclick= 
  "if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?'))
    location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { Id = Model.id })';
  else
    return false;"
  >Delete</button>
}
```

But I don't really care for the old school looking javaScript box. I was hoping to have more control and make a little more rich content by having a display box like the confirmation window C# has. Is there anything supported by the MVC framework to do this? I haven't had much luck finding something.

Comment: I don't think there's anything native, but I imagine there are a number of confirmation dialogs implemented as jQuery plugins.  And since ASP.NET MVC comes with jQuery by default then I imagine those are an option.

Comment: Thanks David, I don't have much experience with JQuery, but I will take a look. I just find it hard to believe that such a strong framework doesn't provide a default modal window to use.

Comment: Well, ASP.NET MVC is more of a server-side framework.  What you're describing is client-side UI functionality, and Microsoft has in general relied on external libraries to cover that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code mentioned above, you did all stuff using inline click event. In my point of you you can use jQuery for better control.

```
<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>

<script>

$('#btnDelete').click(function(){
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?'))
    location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { Id = Model.id })';
  else
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Or use jQuery Plugings like jquery.confirm - http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/ for much fancy ui.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with an example and a resource to utilize.